# Basic error recovery with FParsec

Tags: .net, f#, fparsec

Assume I've this parser:

```
let test p str =
    match run p str with
    | Success(result, _, _)   -> printfn "Success: %A" result
    | Failure(errorMsg, _, _) -> printfn "Failure: %s" errorMsg

let myStatement =
    choice (seq [
                pchar '2' >>. pchar '+' .>> pchar '3' .>> pchar ';';
                pchar '3' >>. pchar '*' .>> pchar '4' .>> pchar ';';
            ])

let myProgram = many myStatement

test myProgram "2+3;3*4;3*4;" // Success: ['+'; '*'; '*']
```

Now, `"2+3;2*4;3*4;3+3;"` will fail with error around `2*4;`. But what is best practice if I want both the error for `2*4;` and `3+3;`? Basically, I want to scan to the nearest ';' but *only if* there is a fatal error. And if that happens I want to aggregate the errors.

Kind regards, Lasse Espeholt

**Update:** `recoverWith` is a nice solution, thanks! But given:

```
let myProgram = 
    (many1 (myStatement |> recoverWith '�')) <|>% []

test myProgram "monkey"
```

I would expect to get `[]` with no errors. Or maybe a bit more "fair":

```
let myProgram = 
    (attempt (many1 (myStatement |> recoverWith '�'))) <|>% []
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

FParsec has no built-in support for recovering from fatal parser errors that would allow you to obtain partial parser results and collect errors from multiple positions. However, it's pretty easy to define a custom combinator function for this purpose.

For example, to recover from errors in your simple statement parser you could define the following `recoverWith` combinator:

```
open FParsec

type UserState = {
    Errors: (string * ParserError) list
} with
    static member Create() = {Errors = []}

type Parser<'t> = Parser<'t, UserState>

// recover from error by skipping to the char after the next newline or ';'
let recoverWith errorResult (p: Parser<_>) : Parser<_> =    
  fun stream ->
    let stateTag = stream.StateTag
    let mutable reply = p stream
    if reply.Status <> Ok then // the parser failed
        let error = ParserError(stream.Position, stream.UserState, reply.Error)
        let errorMsg = error.ToString(stream)
        stream.SkipCharsOrNewlinesWhile(fun c -> c <> ';' && c <> '\n') |> ignore                        
        stream.ReadCharOrNewline() |> ignore
        // To prevent infinite recovery attempts in certain situations,
        // the following check makes sure that either the parser p 
        // or our stream.Skip... commands consumed some input.
        if stream.StateTag <> stateTag then
            let oldErrors = stream.UserState.Errors
            stream.UserState <- {Errors = (errorMsg, error)::oldErrors}     
            reply <- Reply(errorResult)
    reply
```

You could then use this combinator as follows:

```
let myStatement =
    choice [
        pchar '2' >>. pchar '+' .>> pchar '3' .>> pchar ';'
        pchar '3' >>. pchar '*' .>> pchar '4' .>> pchar ';'
    ]

let myProgram = 
    many (myStatement |> recoverWith '�') .>> eof

let test p str =
    let printErrors (errorMsgs: (string * ParserError) list) =        
        for msg, _ in List.rev errorMsgs do
            printfn "%s" msg        

    match runParserOnString p (UserState.Create()) "" str with
    | Success(result, {Errors = []}, _) -> printfn "Success: %A" result
    | Success(result, {Errors = errors}, _) ->
        printfn "Result with errors: %A\n" result
        printErrors errors
    | Failure(errorMsg, error, {Errors = errors}) -> 
        printfn "Failure: %s" errorMsg
        printErrors ((errorMsg, error)::errors)
```

Testing with `test myProgram "2+3;2*4;3*4;3+3"` would yield the output:

```
Result with errors: ['+'; '�'; '*'; '�']

Error in Ln: 1 Col: 6
2+3;2*4;3*4;3+3
     ^
Expecting: '+'

Error in Ln: 1 Col: 14
2+3;2*4;3*4;3+3
             ^
Expecting: '*'
```

**Update:**

Hmm, I thought you wanted to recover from a fatal error in order to collect multiple error messages and maybe produce a partial result. Something that would for example be useful for syntax highlighting or allowing your users to fix more than one error at a time.

Your update seems to suggest that you just want to ignore parts of the input in case of a parser error, which is much simpler:

```
let skip1ToNextStatement =
    notEmpty // requires at least one char to be skipped
        (skipManySatisfy (fun c -> c <> ';' && c <> '\n') 
         >>. optional anyChar) // optional since we might be at the EOF

let myProgram =     
    many (attempt myStatement <|> (skip1ToNextStatement >>% '�'))
    |>> List.filter (fun c -> c <> '�')
```

**Update 2:**

The following is a version of `recoverWith` that doesn't aggregate errors and only tries to recover from an error if the argument parser consumed input (or changed the parser state in any other way):

```
let recoverWith2 errorResult (p: Parser<_>) : Parser<_> =
  fun stream ->
    let stateTag = stream.StateTag
    let mutable reply = p stream
    if reply.Status <> Ok && stream.StateTag <> stateTag then
        stream.SkipCharsOrNewlinesWhile(fun c -> c <> ';' && c <> '\n') |> ignore
        stream.ReadCharOrNewline() |> ignore
        reply <- Reply(errorResult)
    reply
```

Comment: +1 Nice, thanks :) If you don't mind, I've updated the question a bit.

Comment: Hhm, no I want to recover. But only if something is consumed. Currently your first answer is fine for my application so I'll accept that :) However, I might need the more later.

Comment: If you only want to recover when a parser function fails after it has consumed input, how do you expect to parse `"monkey"`, where the `myStatement` parser will always fail without having consumed any input?

Comment: Whoops! :( In the question I forgot to remove `.>> eof`. I'm sorry for wasting your time. Now, if `|> recoverWith...` is removed, it succeeds, but it fails when it is there. In this case I would expect `recoverWith` to do nothing when nothing is consumed.

Comment: I've added another version of `recoverWith` to my reply. If you gave me a little more context in your question, I might be able to provide a better answer.

Comment: @StephenTolksdorf Super! I merged the two versions, essentially adding `&& stream.StateTag <> stateTag` to the first version. That works :) Thank you. And thanks for FParsec by the way ;)

Comment: @StephanTolksdorf I have to say it's very nice of you to keep an eye out for FParsec questions and help people who are using it.

Comment: Unfortunately, `recoverWith` will report false positives when the "recoverable" parser is used in a `sep(End)By` parser. It seems that this way the `sep(End)By` parser is signaled for the end of the sequence. I wish I could suggest a fix but I lack the knowledge...